# TypeScript custom typecheck for string length

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm writing a react component that needs a string prop with a length of less than 10 characters.

I want the compiler to throw an error if a user passes a string with a length greater than 10.

```
interface ComponentProps {
    word: StringLessThanTenChar
}

const Component: React.FC<ComponentProps> = props => {
  return <div>{props.word}</div>;
};
```

```
<Component word="thisIsAStringLongerThan10Chars" />
```

How do I create a custom type to check this and throw an error?

Comment: @keikai - if you make your comment as an answer, I will accept as answer.

Comment: You would need refinement types to be able to do this in compile time which typescript doesn't support so you can only check it in runtime

Comment: Check this: https://medium.com/@lemoine.benoit/refinement-types-in-typescript-or-how-to-check-that-a-number-must-be-positive-at-compile-time-342c1e6e90e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.First, it's not supported by typescript at this moment

Refer: Issue about [Suggestion of Regex-validated string type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579)

---

2.You can use **regex** to limit the length of string

For example:

```
/^.{0,10}$/i
```

Try it online: https://www.regextester.com/?fam=115411

---

3.You can use [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to test if a value fit your regex in js

```
xxxx.test(yourValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to make a `type` which checks for string length. You should do this programmatically.

You could do it by a regex or by length. Something like this.

```
const string = 'lalalalalalalallallalalala'

const stringLength = strin.split('').length
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

interface ComponentProps {
    word: StringLessThanTenChar
}

const Mycomponent = props => {
    return <>{props.word}</>
}

Mycomponent.propTypes = {
  word: chkLength
}

function chkLength(props:ComponentProps , propName:any, componentName = 'ANONYMOUS') {
  if (props[propName]) {
    let value = props[propName];
    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        if(value.length > 10) {
            new Error(propName + ' in ' + componentName + " is accept maximum 10 length of strings");
        }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```